# How to know if a query was retrieved from MySQL cache or not? (w/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, caching

I have a few instances on my website where a query has to be called twice (Once on page load, and once via AJAX tabs within the page itself). Not typical I know, but I can't pass the values to the AJAX page as URL parameters because they can be easily manipulated, so I have to run the query again.

Anyway, my question is, how can I make sure that the second instance of the query was retrieved from the cache or not?

Second *optional* question, is there a more optimal approach for passing critical values (That were already retrieved on page load) via AJAX than URL parameters, or having to run the query again?

Comment: Which cache are you referring to? And how do you pass the values on page load?

Comment: MySQL Query Cache. I retrieve the values first time (on page load)  with a single query. I have to run that same query again in the AJAX-requested page because I don't trust passing them through the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal answer would be [ajax send post data](http://www.google.de/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=ajax+post+data). And I would really go for that.

Another option would be to cache the query result server-side in the session variable. However, everything that you send to the client can be tampered with by the client. It really doesn't matter when he can do that. If you are afraid that someone will tamper with the data then use [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Comment: Values can still be manipulated with the post data. I'm passing critical user data so I would prefer if the values were not tampered with.